# System Tray temporary file shutdown hook

Tags: java, debugging

I have created a temporary file in my program which will be deleted by a shutdown hook though the file is not deleting when I forcefully shutdown otherwise when I exit gracefully though Exit JButton it does delete the file through shutdown hook. Where am I going wrong?

```
public class SystemTrayPostItNotes{

static File file = new File("C:\\Users\\...\Desktop\\On.txt");

public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception{
    if(file.exists()){
     System.out.println("another exists");
    }else{
    file.createNewFile();
    PopupMenu popUp = new PopupMenu();
    MenuItem exit = new MenuItem("Exit");
    popUp.add(exit);
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\GeoGebra_icon_edit.png");
    TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Post It Notes Program", popUp);
    SystemTrayPostItNotes tray = new SystemTrayPostItNotes();
    SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(trayIcon);
    addShutdownHook();
         trayIcon.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
              MainGuiNotes notes = new MainGuiNotes();
          }
          });
          exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
               System.exit(0);
           }
           });
    }
}


public static void addShutdownHook()throws Exception{
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){
      public void run(){


   file.delete();

   }
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) for `addShutdownHook` clearly states that your hook may not be executed if the JVM is shut down forcefully. There is no way to get code to run "for sure" upon shut down of your application.

BTW, if all you want to do is delete a file upon JVM shut down, you can ask the runtime to do so using [`File.deleteOnExit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29). This method is of course subject to the previous paragraph.

If you [properly](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0484.html) create a temporary file (inside the temporary files directory and so on), the OS might take care of cleaning out any strays every now and then.